# running mail doc, server link not working properly

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula

Problem :

1. Using Agent run and send mail give a different link
2. Mail Contain a link which is not include database
3. I set it send to a yahoo mail

   ```
   Sub Initialize()
   Print"Agent:First Reminder for LateIn Reason started running at " & DateValue(Now()) & "," + TimeValue(Now())
   Dim ss As New NotesSession
   Dim db As NotesDatabase
   Dim LateInVw As NotesView
   Dim LateInDocs As NotesViewEntryCollection
   Dim LateEntry As NotesViewEntry
   Dim LateDoc As NotesDocument
   Dim StaffVw As NotesView, StaffDoc As NotesDocument
   Dim MailDoc As NotesDocument
   Dim rtBody As NotesRichTextItem
   Dim sysdoc As NotesDocument, sysVw As NotesView
   Dim AttVw As NotesView, Attdoc As NotesDocument

   Set db=ss.Currentdatabase

   Set sysVw=db.getview("($System Settings)")
   Set sysdoc=sysvw.getfirstdocument
   If sysdoc Is Nothing Then Exit Sub


   Set LateInVw=db.getview("(Testing Late-In Time Records)")


   Set StaffVw=db.getview("($Active Staff by ID)")

   Set AttVw = db.Getview("($Effective Attendance Setting By ID)")
   tdy=Datevalue(Now)

   'get all time records for today
   Set LateInDocs=LateInVw.Allentries
   Set lateEntry=LateInDocs.getfirstentry
   Do While Not LateEntry Is Nothing
       Set LateDoc=LateEntry.Document
       Set Attdoc=Attvw.Getdocumentbykey(LateDoc.TStaffID(0), True)
       If Attdoc.LateAtt(0)="Yes" Then
       If LateDoc.LateReason(0)=""  Then
           If Not ApprovedLateIn(LateDoc, LateDoc.TAmend(0), False) Then
           'get staff mail
               Set staffDoc=StaffVw.Getdocumentbykey(LateDoc.TStaffID(0), True)
               If Not staffdoc Is Nothing Then
               'send email with link to main menu
                   If email$<>staffDoc.email(0) Then
                   '   email$=staffDoc.email(0)
                       email$="chee111385@gmail.com"
                       Set Maildoc=New NotesDocument(db)
                       Set maildoc=db.Createdocument()
                       maildoc.Form="First Reminder Notification"
                       maildoc.Subject="Smartcard Attendance System: Late-In Notification for " +Format$(LateDoc.TDate(0),"dd/mm/yyyy")
                       Maildoc.StaffName=staffDoc.StaffName(0)
                       maildoc.Sendto="chee111385@gmail.com"
                   '   maildoc.NotifyDate=LateDoc.Tdate(0)
                       maildoc.NotifyTime=Timevalue(LateDoc.TAmend(0))
                       maildoc.NotesServer=sysdoc.ServerPath(0)
                       maildoc.NotesDBPath=sysdoc.DBPath(0)
                       maildoc.send(True)
                   End If
               End If
           End If 'check against unimas's jadual kedatangan
       End If 'check for late in reason
       End If 'check late-in on/off in attendance settings
       Set LateEntry=LateInDocs.Getnextentry(LateEntry)
   Loop


   End Sub
   ```

I will attach my image file and coding here

[image: wrong path come out from mail]

[image: correct path]

from this 2 image you can see that, actually i want to put as a

notes://Mulu/SmartCard Attedancce/sas-server.nsf/Scais Main?OpenFrameset

but result of the mail send out is

notes:////Scais Main?OpenFrameset

which is no server and database. I am not sure what part of my coding is wrong

Another attachment will be the form i use as mail.form
[image: Form]

[image: hotspot link include script]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: Sending an external mail with a custom form like you do it is not the best Idea, as the target system might not be able to render everything accordingly.

That said, I would first create a document that contains all data and then RENDER it to a maildoc. code would look like this:

```
Dim Templatedoc as NotesDocument
Dim body as NotesRichtextItem

Set Templatedoc=New NotesDocument(db)
Set Templatedoc=db.Createdocument()
Templatedoc.Form="First Reminder Notification"
Templatedoc.StaffName=staffDoc.StaffName(0)
'   maildoc.NotifyDate=LateDoc.Tdate(0)
Templatedoc.NotifyTime=Timevalue(LateDoc.TAmend(0))
Templatedoc.NotesServer=sysdoc.ServerPath(0)
Templatedoc.NotesDBPath=sysdoc.DBPath(0)

Set maildoc=New NotesDocument(db)
maildoc.Form = "Memo"
maildoc.Subject="Smartcard Attendance System: Late-In Notification for " +Format$(LateDoc.TDate(0),"dd/mm/yyyy")
maildoc.Sendto="chee111385@gmail.com"

Set body = New NotesRichtextItem( maildoc, "Body" )
Call Templatedoc.RenderToRTItem( body )

maildoc.send(True)
```

Second: You set two fields (NotesServer and NotesDBPath) to compute your Link. But your link in reality is computed from environment- variables, and these are not set on the server.

Change your Link- Computation- Formula to:

```
srv := NotesServer;
pth := NotesDBPath;
```

That should do the trick for the link.

Comment: ok, the link u suggested is already work ..which is correct..but it still not allow me to open the frameset itself...it still go to "view"  which contain the data which is . "LateInVw". I only loop this view for who are late, and force them go to the frameset to enter reason of late~